# PR2 Dashboard Icons Source

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone have the source image files for the PR2 Dashboard Icons?

[image: image description]

Specifically, I'm looking for the blank images without any icons on them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36137/pr2-dashboard-icons-source/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I uploaded the PSD template here:

https://code.ros.org/svn/data/trunk/pr2_dashboard/glassbutton2.psd

You'll have to sort through the layer combos if you want to export the blank images.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-06-10**:
I don't have a copy of photoshop ATM, but opening it in GIMP gives me largely black and white layers. Otherwise, this is exactly what I was looking for.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-06-11**:
I have confirmed it is GIMP's fault.